# where can i find component like this in c# windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

where can i find a component like this in c# windows Form ?

Comment: Looks like a PropertyGrid with expanded categories.

Comment: "alamat" just a label and "asdasdada" just a text where i input like textbox

Comment: what i mean is that "are you a pinoy?", XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the TreeView with multiple columns

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx

sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns

Comment: its look like difficult

Comment: not really, what is your datasource? is it list/ienumerable or datatable?

Comment: no..see at my pict, first column is just a label and second column is a textBox. so i can input any text to that field..

Answer (score -2):

You can use DataGrid.
Add a reference for DataGrid.